# Getting files from Google Drive "Computers" into Google Colab

Tags: google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

I need to make use of Google Colab's GPUs, but also need to constantly upload new files and make slight adjustments to other files so I used Google's Backup/Sync tools to automatically stream a folder from my local machine into Google Drive so that new/updated/deleted files are automatically loaded. The problem is that I can't figure out how to get the data from the computer into Colab.

Most solutions I've seen on stack overflow use

```
 from google.colab import drive
 drive.mount("/content/gdrive",force_remount=True)
```

The problem with this is that upon doing this, inside of /content/gdrive there is only the folder "My Drive", whereas the files from my computer get saved in a different area "Computers/My Computer/". Thus these files aren't accessible using this method. Is there a way in Colab to be able to access the content in  Computers/My Computer/ ?

The only other solutions I have seen have some code inside of Colab allowing you to directly upload files, which doesn't suit my purposes since I don't want to have to manually upload files every time.

Comment: Have you tried to add the folder from your Computers/My Computer/ i.e., the synced device to My Drive, which should possibly grant you access to the required folder.

Comment: Also have a look at this which may possibly serve your purpose: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53199781/mount-computers-of-google-drive-to-colaboratory

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mount "Computers" of Google Drive to Colaboratory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53199781/mount-computers-of-google-drive-to-colaboratory)

Comment: Also let me know if you found an alternate solution and if so do share that.

Answer (score 0):

In Colab, you might not be able to access any folder or files other than "/content/drive/My Drive". For example, you are not able to access files under '/content/drive/Computers/My Laptop/Project_R_Py/lib_py'.

You can simply go to google drive, right click that folder ("lib_py") and choose "Add Shortcut to Drive". After that you should be able to access that folder by specifying "/content/drive/My Drive/Project_R_Py/lib_py"

Hope this helps